# Asp.Net Identity Get Users by Claims

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity-3

How could I get a list of users by the claims they have? I have tried the following query on the UserManager.Users property of IQueryable

```
await (from t in Users
from c in t.Claims
where c.ClaimType == "CompanyId" && c.ClaimValue == Id
select t).Execute();
```

This returns no results.
Is my query formed wrong?
I am using Web.Api v2.2

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind it Works like this

`var q = from t in Users
          where t.Claims.Any(c => c.ClaimType == Claims.CompanyId && c.ClaimValue == cid)
          select t;
 var users = q.ToList();`